# NPM install error and build failure on Angular

Tags: angular, npm

I am new working with angular so apologies if this is basic stuff.

I have been handed a new repo to work on but am unable to build it through cmd.

I am trying to run a `npm install` and `npm start` on a work project, but am getting the following error:

> ```
> npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
> npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! While resolving: @angular/cdk@12.2.13
> npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@14.2.12
> ```

when afterwards running `--legacy-peer-deps` I get this:

> ```
> npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
> npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@angular-devkit/core@10.2.3',
> npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>= 10.13.0', npm: '^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6', yarn: '>= 1.13.0' },
> npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v18.16.1', npm: '9.8.0' }
> npm WARN EBADENGINE }
>   
> added 1498 packages, and audited 1499 packages in 34s
>
> 145 packages are looking for funding
>   run `npm fund` for details
>
> 40 vulnerabilities (14 moderate, 23 high, 3 critical)
>
> To address issues that do not require attention, run:
>   npm audit fix
> ```

when running `npm audit fix` I get the same, if I even try to run `npm start` it simply errors and breaks.

I need it to be able to run so that I can build an model and work on the project.

Comment: As the error says, you are trying to build Angular v10(?) with Node v18, and that's just too high of a version. Try installing Node v10 (as it suggests in `required:`).

Comment: I just tried it but no, I get this error message following:

The Angular CLI requires a minimum Node.js version of either v14.20, v16.14 or v18.10.

Please update your Node.js version or visit https://nodejs.org/ for additional instructions.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

Comment: Can you share your `package.json` you likely have huge mismatch in package versinos.

Comment: {
  "name": "cm-provisiones-frontend",
  "version": "1.0.1-beta.15",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "build-patch": "npm version patch && ng build --configuration production --aot && npm run post-build",
    "build-minor": "npm version minor && ng build --configuration production --aot && npm run post-build",
    "build-major": "npm version major && ng build --configuration production --aot && npm run post-build",


all it let's me upload

Comment: Add the `package.json` to your question rather than the comments please :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using nvm run

**Step: 01**

nvm install 18.1.0

> 10.13.0 Install this version

nvm use 18.1.0

> Use the 10.13.0

if you didn't install nvm try to follow this [Using Node version manager](https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/how-to-install-use-node-version-manager-nvm/)

**Step: 02**

You are using 18.16.1, but the message says it requires 10.13.0. Not 18.16.1 or greater. It requires exactly 18.16.1.

If it's your package.json with the engines field causing this issue, change it to say 18.16.1 or greater:

```
      "engines": {
    "node": ">=18.16.1"
  },
```

Comment: Why does your answer say "nvm install **18**.1.0" and follow that with a quote (who are you quoting?) saying "**10.13.0** Install this version"? That's not what the command `nvm install 18.1.0` will do. Also, the message says it requires 10.13.0, not 18.16.1, so why do you state "It requires exactly 18.16.1" when it clearly doesn't?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).